# WPF ListView Always show complete items

Tags: wpf, listview, scrollviewer

I've got an app with multiple ListView controls where there's a requirement that the item's in the ListView must be fully visible. There should never be partial ListViewItem's showing in the list. If the user releases the ScrollViewer at a position that ends up showing a partial item, then the list should "snap" and correct itself so that only complete items are displayed.

Has anyone done this before? I think I'm going to need to overload ListView and/or ScrollViewer to do this. I'm looking for suggestions on how to approach this. Thanks.

Here is one of my lists:

```
<ctrls:SnapList x:Name="PART_ProductList" 
                                            ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"  
                                            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
                                            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                                            ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ProductFinderItem}" 
                                            Canvas.Top="373" Canvas.Left="75"
                                            Height="910" Width="900" >

                            <ctrls:SnapList.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <VirtualizingStackPanel VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" />
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ctrls:SnapList.ItemsPanel>

                            <ctrls:SnapList.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                    <ScrollViewer  x:Name="Scroller" VerticalAlignment="Top"  CanContentScroll="True" Style="{StaticResource VertScrollViewer}" Focusable="false" >
                                                <ItemsPresenter   />
                                            </ScrollViewer>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                            </ctrls:SnapList.Template>
                        </ctrls:SnapList>
```

Comment: Which ScrollViewer are you talking about? Do you have a ScrollViewer in a Grid (or something) containing multiple ListViews and when that ScrollViewer changes position then you want to make sure all ListViewItems are visible? For a ListView itself, I can't even get it to display partial items.

Comment: I'm talking about the ScrollViewer in the list's ControlTemplate. I added the xaml for one of the lists to my post. The ScrollViewer I am talking about is the one with x:Name="Scroller" in the example XAML.

Comment: *ListBox* has the exact same behavior by default. Can you use a *ListBox* instead of a *ListView*?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for the [ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.cancontentscroll.aspx) Property

If you know the maximum size of the item in the ListView, make sure that the ListView's Height is the same size, or a multiple of the item height.

Working Example:

```
<ListView ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
            Height="200">

    <ListBoxItem Height="50"
                    Content="Test1" />
    <ListBoxItem Height="50"
                    Content="Test2" />
    <ListBoxItem Height="50"
                    Content="Test3" />
    <ListBoxItem Height="50"
                    Content="Test4" />
    <ListBoxItem Height="50"
                    Content="Test5" />
    <ListBoxItem Height="50"
                    Content="Test6" />
    <ListBoxItem Height="50"
                    Content="Test7" />
    <ListBoxItem Height="50"
                    Content="Test8" />
    <ListBoxItem Height="50"
                    Content="Test9" />
    <ListBoxItem Height="50"
                    Content="Test10" />

</ListView>
```

> Content in a ScrollViewer can be scrolled in terms of physical units
>   or logical units. Physical units are device independent pixels.
>   Logical units are used for scrolling items within an ItemsControl. The
>   default behavior of the ScrollViewer is to use physical units to
>   scroll its content. However, in cases where the CanContentScroll is
>   set to true, the content could use logical units to scroll. For
>   example, ListBox, ListView, and other controls that inherit from
>   ItemsControl use logical units to scroll. If CanContentScroll is true,
>   the values of the ExtentHeight, ScrollableHeight, ViewportHeight, and
>   VerticalOffset properties are number of items, instead of physical
>   units.
>
> If you require physical scrolling instead of logical scrolling, wrap
>   the host Panel element in a ScrollViewer and set its CanContentScroll
>   property to false. Physical scrolling is the default scroll behavior
>   for most Panel elements.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ListView.ScrollIntoView`?

Comment: ScrollIntoView will scroll an item into view, but it does nothing to ensure only entire items are visible in a list. Even if it did, I'd still need to know when to call it (eg. when partial items are showing).

Comment: Your current question is more clear. Previously it was more like that you wanted your selection to be completely visible. Instead, you do not want any partial items showing in your list at all. Right?

Comment: Right. My question is the same as I originally posted. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try keeping track of the scrollview's current scroll, then get the height of all items. Then you'll know how to calculate the correct offset for each item. When they release the scroll animate to the closest offset.

[ScrollInfo to get the current scroll offset and info.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrollinfo.aspx)

[Scroll to vertical offset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset.aspx)